# Sitemap's lastmod field update for performance related CSS and JS changes

Tags: google, sitemap

I understand Google mostly ignores lastmod field in sitemaps. However, as a practice, I used to update the tag whenever I make visible changes like content updates.  Now, I made significant performance related changes to CSS and JS files. I aggregated several CSS files into one big file. I moved blocking-scripts to the footer, and so on. The changes were significant and resulted in a performance boost. However, the user will not notice anything different on the content part. In such a case, for a sincere adopter of the lastmod tag, what will your advice be. Should I update the lastmod tag or not?

Comment: If you know Google ignores the field, why do you ask?  It doesn't matter if you update it or not for Google.

Comment: That was a question for a 'just in case' scenario. Google mostly ignores lastmod but there is no proof to say it completely ignores for every website. Assuming Google respects those webmasters who do a good job in maintaining lastmod and assuming I am one of those, should I be concerned that Google may expect a field update even if CSS or JS change (without affecting visible content)?